# Support for ESP8266 and Firebase

Tags: firebase, esp8266

I am trying to connect to Firebase from an ESP8266 microcontroller. This device has limited RAM and can't handle large TLS fragments. The developer who supports TLS for ESP8266 implemented [Maximum Fragment Length Negotiation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3546#section-3.2) only to find that Firebase servers ignore it. Is somebody at Firebase listening? Can anything be done to turn on this option on your servers?

You can see the discussion [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/43), towards the bottom.

Comment: Have you seen this article by chance? http://www.devacron.com/arduino-firebase/  Since there is firmware for the ESP8266 that allows you to use the Arduino IDE I suggest you try to flash your ESP with that firmware and try and implement the example in the link provided.

Comment: Also I believe you can replace the 8pin ram chip with a larger one (possibly up to 4MB if I recall correctly).

Comment: I have Firebase working fine with my ESP8266, as long as the amount of data communicated at once is small. Sending a single temperature works fine. However, it fails when I make too big a change to the Firebase. Firebase sends a very large block, too big for the ESP8266 TLS code.

Comment: The point of using ESP8266 is that it is inexpensive. Modifying each one to have more RAM is not a good solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use some Esp8266's with Firestore to monitor my foil tunnel for tomatoes and it works good.
I use the Firebase-ESP-Client from mobizt.

https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP-Client

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).